The Cryptic Constellation
You are a renowned cryptographer who has been contacted by an ancient order known as "The Keepers of the Stars." They guard a secret message passed down through generations, hidden in the stars themselves. The message is said to unlock the location of a hidden treasure, but only the most skilled cryptographers can decode it.
The Keepers present you with the following encrypted string, claiming it holds the key to the secret:
XJHDQVKFLTMZNGBWROAPYEISUC
YMIQKHFCWPLJDZNOBVTGAESXRQ
NOBEZLXPFYDGCRIMQHWTJUKVSA

After a few days of struggling to solve the message, I was still unsuccessful. Then, as if by a miracle from God, three new messages suddenly appeared.
Hint 1:

"Align the stars in your mind, for the first and the last must be intertwined."

Hint 2:

"The desert winds blow left and right; shift the sands to reveal the light."

Hint 3:

"he path to knowledge is often prime, with steps measured in intervals sublime."


Is the doubled Q on the second line intentional?

@LukasRotter The double Q is indeed intentional

Added hints to the post :)

How many letters long is the answer?
